# Mongoid ruby where query returns incorrect results

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I have a User class which embeds_many messages. A Message has a 'source' field.
I'm trying to get a message with a specific 'source':

`m = user.messages.where(source: 'reward').first`

I get nil since there aren't any. Then I add one myself, and run the query again but it still returns nil.
When I do instead:
`m = user.messages.to_a.find {|m| m.source == 'reward'}`

It works as expected.
It seems like there is some caching here that after the first query, keeps the data and ignores the following insert, but I can't find any way to disable it (QueryCache is disabled and not relevant).

What can it be?

Comment: can you try running user.reload and then running the query again? If it works then it is probably a cache issue. If it doesn't then I would assume a bug in the where implementation of the embedded object.

Comment: If I save & reload it works, but then I prefer the to_a solution. The question is why reload needed? what cache is used here and how do I prevent it?

Comment: So that confirms you suspicion that it is a cache issue. I would open a bug for the monoid  project at https://jira.mongodb.org/projects/MONGOID/issues

Answer (score 0):

Queries on embedded associations are done in the application process. If `user` is loaded and you add more messages to that user using anything other than the loaded `user` object (e.g. mongo shell or a different instance of Rails console), the messages in the loaded `user` won't be updated. See https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-relations/#querying-loaded-associations.

- If you only want the data from the embedded associations, query the top level model with appropriate projection to retrieve the embedded association. See https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-queries/#projection.
- If you need data from both the top level model and the embedded association, reload the top level model as suggested in the comment.

Comment: I'm adding the messages to the loaded user using the loaded user in the same console

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround could be querying the embedded association. In your case your query would look like this:

```
m = user.where('message.source' => 'reward').first
```

More examples here: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-relations/index.html#querying-embedded-associations